# MVC JSON response with bad request

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

During developing ASP.NET MVC 4 application I encounter problem with returning notification in JSON in my Controllers action. Below I attached code I am using to send notification:

```
return GetNotificationResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, notification);

private JsonResult GetNotificationResult(HttpStatusCode code, string notification)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int) code;
        return Json(new { Notification = notification });
    }
```

When I test it on localhost it works as expected (it returns status code BadRequest and body contains JSON with notification).

Hovewer, when i deploy this code as Web App in Azure then it returns just BadRequest without JSON notification.

What can cause different results in invoking this code on cloud vs on localhost?

Comment: Try adding this to your `web.config`: `<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
 </system.webServer>`

Comment: @Igor it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Good deal. I wrote it below as the answer, please mark it as such if it was helpful using the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
</system.webServer>
```

---

Documentation on [httpErrors](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)

> **PassThrough**: Leaves the response untouched if an existing response exists.